# C++ creating image

Tags: c++, image

I haven't been programming in C++ for a while, and now I have to write a simple thing, but it's driving me nuts.

I need to create a bitmap from a table of colors:
`char image[200][200][3];`

First coordinate is width, second height, third colors: RGB. How to do it?

Thanks for any help.
Adam

Comment: What file format? What OS or libraries are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows, simple Visual Studio Win32 application.

Comment: Are you asking about a Windows GDI BITMAP, or a .bmp file?

Comment: I would like to create a simple .bmp file.

Comment: OK, I will try the option with setting headers. But is there really no simple way of creating an bitmap file: just setting the pixel color values and saving to file?

Comment: This is simple.  You create two structs, fill them with data, write them, then write the pixel data.  The only thing simpler than a BMP is probably a PPM or RAW file.

Comment: Kinda lame, isn't it? They have LoadBitmap for loading a BMP, but nothing for saving one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm sure you've already checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format.

With that information in hand we can write a quick BMP with:

```
// setup header structs bmpfile_header and bmp_dib_v3_header before this (see wiki)
// * note for a windows bitmap you want a negative height if you're starting from the top *
// * otherwise the image data is expected to go from bottom to top *

FILE * fp = fopen ("file.bmp", "wb");
fwrite(bmpfile_header, sizeof(bmpfile_header), 1, fp);
fwrite(bmp_dib_v3_header, sizeof(bmp_dib_v3_header_t), 1, fp);

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)  {
 for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
  fwrite(&image[j][i][2], 1, 1, fp);
  fwrite(&image[j][i][1], 1, 1, fp);
  fwrite(&image[j][i][0], 1, 1, fp);
 }
}

fclose(fp);
```

If setting up the headers is a problem let us know.

Edit: I forgot, BMP files expect BGR instead of RGB, I've updated the code (surprised nobody caught it).

Comment: With the question being tagged C++, not C, it would be nicer to see file-streams being used.

Comment: I find it easier to output binary data with C-style functions, but I do recommend the file streams approach generally.

Comment: @RonWarholic definitely agree with you there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/), comprehensive library etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to find out, how the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) (that's what you mean by a bitmap, right?) is defined. Then I would convert the array to that format and print it to the file.

If that's an option, I would also consider trying to find an existing library for BMP files creation, and just use it.

Sorry if what I said is already obvious for you, but I don't know on which stage of the process you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For simple image operations I highly recommend [Cimg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/). This library works like a charm, and is extremely easy to use. You just have to include a header file in your code. It literally took me less than 10 minutes to compile and test.

If you want to do more complicated image operations however, I would go with [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) as suggested by dagoof.

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable to initialise the function as a simple 1 dimensional array.

ie (Where bytes is the number of bytes per pixel)

```
 char image[width * height * bytes];
```

You can then access the relevant position in the array as follows

```
 char byte1 = image[(x * 3) + (y * (width * bytes)) + 0];
 char byte2 = image[(x * 3) + (y * (width * bytes)) + 1];
 char byte3 = image[(x * 3) + (y * (width * bytes)) + 2];
```

Comment: When the sizes are known at compile-time, why do all this, which the compiler does for you automatically?

Comment: oops fixed the index problem.  As for why do it explicity?  That way you gain a far better understanding of EXACTLY what is going on.   Each to their own.  I, personally, prefer not to treat the compiler as a black box ... if width, height and bytes are constant values they will be optimised out anyway :)

Comment: Significantly easier to see exactly what is going on as well, IMHO.

Comment: I can use a `char image[width][height][bytes];` and know EXACTLY what's going on.  Depending on "they will be optimized out anyway" seems to be the only black box here.  And it's NOT easier to see what's going on, as it appears 'x' is dominant over 'y' (including in your initialization), but what you actually do is more like `image[height][width][bytes]`!  This can lead to subtle errors.

Comment: Each to their own.  Good luck interpreting someone else's image using a 3 dimensional array ...